# Elastic search query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to retrieve documents based on the following query:

```
POST _search
{
    "size": 1, 
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                   "range":{
                        "myfield": {
                            "from": "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z",
                            "to": "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z"
                        }
                    }
               },
                {"term": {"myfield1.myfield2" : "myvalue"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

which doesnot return any result. There might be a problem with my syntax. I'd appreciate if anyone can help.

here is the structure of the document:

```
"_source": {
    "myfield": "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00",
    "myfield1": {
        "myfield2": "myvalue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The field of the `term` query is not correct.

Instead of this:

```
{"term": {"myfield.myfield1.myfield2" : "myvalue"}}
```

Try this:

```
{"term": {"myfield1.myfield2" : "myvalue"}}
```

Comment: same problem. Returns null as output

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index as well as a sample document that is supposed to match your query?

Comment: "hits": {
      "total": 187,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "something",
            "_type": "something",
            "_id": "something",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "eventVersion": "1.05",
               "myfield1":{
                    "myfield2": "soemthing"
                }}}}]}

Comment: you have no date field in there, hence the `range` query doesn't match anything

Comment: range query works fine as long as myfield1.myfield2 query isn't there